# Question about the congruence classes of a square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I've noticed that for any prime $p$ where $p = 2x+1$, a square $w^2$ can only take on $x$ possible congruence classes modulo $p$.

I've also noticed that:

$x^2 \equiv (x+1)^2 \pmod p$

$(x-1)^2 \equiv (x+2)^2 \pmod p$

$\vdots$

$1 \equiv (2x)^2 \pmod p$

For example, for $7$, we have:

$3^2 \equiv 4^2 \pmod 7$

$2^2 \equiv 5^2 \pmod 7$

$1 \equiv 6^2 \pmod 7$

Is this always true for $p > 7$?  If so, why is it true?  If it is not always true, can you give an example where it is not true?

Thanks,

-Larry

Comment: Note that $x-a$ and $x+a+1$ add up to $p$, so if we call one of them $r$, then the other one is $-r$ (mod $p$). Now you see why the squares are equal?

Comment: Thanks!  I had a feeling it was something that simple.

Comment: Actually there are $x+1$ quadratic residues if we include $0$. I'm saying this because that's possibly how you would find it on most web pages.

Comment: Thanks, Barto.  I prefer to use the proper terms. I will remember that.

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ Since $\,x^2 \equiv 2\ $ has root $\,x \equiv 3,\,$ it also has root $\,x\equiv -3\equiv 4.\,$ You are simply observing that $\,a^2 \equiv (-a)^2\equiv (m-a)^2\pmod m.\ \ $

Comment: Thanks, Bill. Time for me now to read up more on quadratic residues and learn more of their fundamental properties.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, given, I will attempt to answer my own question.

First, the reason that the following is true:

$x^2 \equiv (x+1)^2 \pmod p$

$(x-1)^2 \equiv (x+2)^2 \pmod p$

$\vdots$

$1 \equiv (2x)^2 \pmod p$

is because since $p$ is odd:

$x^2 \equiv (-x)^2 \equiv (p-x)^2 \equiv (2x+1 -x)^2 = (x+1)^2 \pmod p$

$(x-1)^2 \equiv (-x+1)^2 \equiv (p -x+1)^2 \equiv (2x+1-x+1)^2 \equiv (x+2)^2 \pmod p$

$\vdots$

$1^2 \equiv (-1^2) \equiv (p-1)^2 \equiv (2x+1-1)^2 \equiv (2x)^2 \pmod p$

There are $x$ possible congruence classes because there are $2x$ congruence classes that not congruent to $0 \pmod p$ and since for each $c^2 \equiv (p-c)^2$, it follows that $w^2$ can only take on $x$ possible values.

If we include $p^2$, it follows that there are $x+1$ distinct congruence classes.   Since each congruence class is called a [quadratic residue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue), it follows that there are $x+1$ quadratric residues.